# error with process while using pip(python command)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, file, pip, process

I have a very confusing problem. When I am using the command pip("pip install " or just "pip"), it returns this:

```
C:\Users\user1>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 177, in _exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_pip.py", line 35, in apply_patches
    import certifi
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 177, in _exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 20, in apply_patches
    certifi_win32.wincerts.CERTIFI_PEM = certifi.where()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 37, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 95, in _tempfile
    os.remove(raw_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Le processus ne peut pas accéder au fichier car ce fichier est utilisé par un autre processus: 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp6tg79str
```

I am on windows, and before that, I restarted my computer, that started a windows update. Is it the origin of the problem?
Also, I uninstall and reinstall python on my computer, but it didn't change anything.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing Python installation folder security permission.

Select properties for folder , Click on the security tab Then Edit.

Add everyone and give them permission to read/write. Save the changes and exit.

they try to test `pip` is working

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: it seemed to be already done. I tried to give up the permision, and give it again, but pip is still not working

Answer (score 0):

That also happened to me.  An internet search showed that others had the same problem after installing `python-certifi-win32`.

Under
`Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages` I found a file
`python-certifi-win32-init.pth` and removed it. Lo!
`pip` is working again.